# A question in the proof of the oscillation of cadlag function on [0, 1]

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

This is a Lemma of Billingsley's *Convergence of Probability Measures* on page 122
[image]

Where $D$ is the set of all the cadlag fuction on $[0,1]$, and 
$$\omega_x[a,b):=sup_{s,t\in [a,b)}|x(s)-x(t)|$$
I am wondering why "Since $x(0)=x(0+)$, we have $t'>0$". For a fixed $\varepsilon$ it can find such a $t>0$, but I think it need to find a $t>0$ suit for any positive $\varepsilon$, and I'm stuck with it. Any help please.

Comment: the cad part in cadlag means right continuous, here any $x$ is right-continuous at 0 (i.e. $x(0)=x(0+)$). This should be enough to prove your claim considering the fact that you want $t°$ as the supremum of all $t\in [0,1]$ such that. 12.4 is true (try absurd reasoning). Best regard.

Comment: @TheBridge I just find out it is enough to prove it for a fixed $\varepsilon$, and the proof is just do that. Then everything else is clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x$ is continuous on the right side at $0$, for $\varepsilon >0$, you can find $\delta >0$ such that $\vert x(u)-x(0) \vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for $\vert u \vert < \delta$.

Then for $u,v \in [0,\delta)$ $$\vert x(u) -x(v) \vert = \vert x(u)-x(0) +x(0)-x(v) \vert < \vert x(u)-x(0) \vert + \vert x(0)-x(v) \vert <\varepsilon$$

Hence you can select $t^\circ =\delta$ and decompose $[0, t^\circ)$ into a single interval equals to itself.

Comment: Ahh, it is sufficient to prove it for a fixed $\varepsilon$. Thank you very mach!